# How does internal linking of questions impact Stack Exchange SEO?

Tags: discussion, seo, linked-questions

I don't understand the difference between linked questions and related ones on Stack Exchange. Are linked questions only put there for the sake of SEO? Does linking questions inside SE (or any other website) have an impact on SEO?

Comment: Regarding the difference - linked are those that have actually been linked to - either in the question, answer or comments. Related are those that our search engine thinks are related.

Comment: Linked questions are not for the purpose of SEO. They are to help people reading the question. They are chosen by humans. Related questions are chosen by software.

Comment: @KateGregory true, with bit more details this can be a suitable answer in my opinion. :)

Comment: Details like the impact on SEO, of which I know nothing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Internal links are always good because they allow page authority to spread around a website.

The more internal links a page has, the more likely it is to be seen by Google as interesting and worthy of ranking. It is the same logic that applies to followers on Twitter or Facebook; the more real ones, the more likely a page is of interest.

Answer (score -2):

As per Matt Cutts, Google Spam Control Manager, describe in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ybpXU0ckKQ) on the account of Google Webmasters:

> Internal links are very good for all websites and everybody should have to do this.